# AFNetworking -1017 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am working on iOS application and facing one strange issue. I am using AFNetworking framework to communicate with server (HTTPS communication). I am retrieving student data from server by using "getStudentData" web service API. It is post request. It works for all user ids except one. It fails when we have a data for more than 450 students. Below are the error details,

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo=0x7bf9c7d0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.fdmobileservices.com/mAccountsWeb/services/speedpass/rpc, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.fdmobileservices.com/mAccountsWeb/services/speedpass/rpc, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,    NSUnderlyingError=0x7bf9a380 "cannot parse response"}
```

As per error description, It tells "Could Not parse", so I think it may be due to server is returning "nil" or some data other than JSON format.

But I am not able to trace it since from application side it directly goes into below method,

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Is there any way from application side to trace root cause? This method works for other user login except one.

I tried using web client to access this service by same user login, it works well and return data of 450 students. I think due to some reason iOS network layer rejects this. I am trying to find out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to do the following with your web-client: 1) ensure HTTP status code is 2xx 2) ensure json response is valid with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: yes  I already tried both but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFNetworkErrors), `kCFURLErrorCannotParseResponse = -1017`. So probably this is saying that there is something wrong in the parameters.

If You're using AFNetworking 2.0, I suggest You to deep debug your response flow with severals breakpoints.
Specifically try to set a breakpoint on `AFURLResponseSerialization.m` at the start of the method:

```
- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
```

Inside the method, if the below condition is true, probably there is something wrong (but you can step into `validateResponse:data:error:` to better understand what's wrong):

```
   if (![self validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response data:data error:error])
```

If the above condition is false you can then check about the generated `responseString`:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:stringEncoding];
```

If you're expecting json data, check that `responseString` is not `nil` and `data` data is valid, maybe also the `stringEncoding`.
Also ensure that the contentType that you're receiving is the one you're expecting.

Comment: Yes I tried to debug "responseObjectForResponse:" method, but It doesn't come into this method, instead goes to "didfailwithError:" ....